# GCM is not working with new app credentials after Introduction of FCM

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM successfully on a Cordova app previously. Having gone to https://console.developers.google.com, created a new app and credentials, it is not working now. But, if I put old google app credentials, it started working.
I have no idea whether after introducing of FCM, new app will only support FCM.

Comment: By credentials, do you mean a Server Key?

Comment: do u mean API server key, project info details ?

Answer (score 0):

From the GCM documentation:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#create-an-api-project

> New Cloud Messaging projects must create a Firebase project in the
>   Firebase console. In this process, you'll generate a configuration
>   file and credentials for your project.

If you need a new sender-id and server-key for a GCM project you should create a new Firebase Project and get the relevant values from: `Setting > Cloud Messaging`